# Unable to play .wav file Using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avplayer

I have some wav files and they completely working with MPMoviePlayer. but not working with AVPlayer. For some reason I have changed my player to AVPlayer. But after implementation I found that some of my audio files are not working with AVPlayer.I have used apples sample code of AVPlayer. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does other format work ? Perhaps it's a coding problem.

Anyway. If your WAV files are ok, import them into iTunes, convert them once (right click on the file into the library), and convert the converted one back to wav (same method). You should then have an iPhone compatible WAV file.

If that does not work, that should be a coding problem  :-)

Try :

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundfileName ofType:fileType];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] == NO) NSLog (@"No file");

AVPlayer* player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[player play];
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. Yes,Other formats are working even other wav files are also working. Sorry but I didnt get how to convert file into iPhone compatible wav. I already mentioned in my question that all these files are working with MPMoviewplayer

Comment: @Armaan : How do you make those file play with AVAudioPlayer (code) ?

Comment: @Armaan : right click, and something like "Convert to...." or "Create a xxxx version"

Comment: I am trying with AVPlayer not with AVAudioPlayer. I checked that file working with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: @Armaan : Just a question. Ok, it's raging. But it's iPhone dev... We must deal with such problems. So if other format work, why don't you use them ? They should also be smaller than WAV files, so your final package would be smaller.

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution works like a charm :). I am using  [self setPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.mPlayerItem]]; And its not working.

Comment: because it was working with MPMoviePlayer. And Client has seen that files are working in iPhone. So I cant say its not supported.

Comment: Ok for the support. But the size of the package is an argument for choosing another format.