# Empty AVMetadataItem using AVAsset with wav file

Tags: audio, avfoundation, metadata

I'm trying to get the metadata of a wav file.

I create an asset of my wav file path like this

```
let inputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilePath)

 // Create AssetTrack
 let asset = AVAsset(url: inputURL)
 guard let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType:.audio).first else {
    return
 }
```

then when I inspect my metadata with `assetTrack.metadata` or even `asset.metadata` I have an empty array.

What would be the right way to get the metadata of a wav file?

Comment: Because of the nature of timed audiovisual media, upon successful initialization of an asset some or all of the values for its keys may not be immediately available. 
Try to create AVPlayerItem, then load it AVPlayer, call prepare to play, and then check tracks

Comment: @IgorKotkovets unfortunately the metadata are still empty with your method. Or maybe I did something wrong `let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset); let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem); let metadata = playerItem.tracks.first!.assetTrack.commonMetadata`.
Does the url path format would be the cause of this? I use something like `file:///Users/me/Desktop/audioFile.wav`

Comment: try to call player.play()

Comment: @IgorKotkovets still the same things, no tracks in the playerItem property and the status of th eplayerItem is set to `unknown`. Does it helps?

Comment: So it doesn't play `wav` file at all? maybe there is a problem with file?
Try to play it using `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: @IgorKotkovets yes it doesn't play anything but it works using `AVAudioPlayer` should I do more setup for using AVPlayer?

Comment: found a link to related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848439/unable-to-play-wav-file-using-avplayer?rq=1

Comment: Try to convert "wav" file to "mp3" and then again to "wav". The way how to convert file see at https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204310

Comment: @IgorKotkovets I'm sorry but it still doesn't work... Or maybe is the way I create metada. What's the common way to do this?